# Unicode characters breaks close-vote reason text

Tags: support, design, user-interface, fonts

The close-vote reason for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19980752/1438393) (10K+ link) looks like below:

[image: Pekka messing up the commas]

The comma should come **after** the little guy (웃    ). I don't know if Pekka would agree, but it would be nice to see this fixed.

Reproduced again (even weirder this time) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20090795/):

[image]

Problem appears on Stack Overflow - Google Chrome 31.0.1650.48 on Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Do you mean `ASCII` or `Unicode`?

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Unicode.

Comment: Excellent! Sometimes I get mixed up, so I didn't edit it myself.

Comment: Oh, and maybe the little guy 웃 does not like having commas behind him... ;)

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this. The dude was getting along fine with the comma (or his duderness if you aren't into the whole brevity thing).

Comment: What environment were you viewing the dude from?

Comment: @AndrewBarber: ASCII is Unicode too.. Perhaps 'Non-ASCII'?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Technically, you are absolutely correct! Though I think people know what is meant here. That said, I do love being technically correct, and being corrected when I'm not! :)

Comment: Oh, and RE @TravisJ; I'm also unable to reproduce it. I see the little dude just fine.

Comment: That looks as if your browser overrides the writing direction for that character. The character itself is `Left_To_Right`, but seems to be displayed Right_To_Left almost.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: I wouldn't be a proper geek if I wasn't being pedantic about technical nuance. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah! One thing that always confuses me about some programmers who aren't careful with their spoken/written language; You would think that being a programmer, they would know how important it is to use *precisely* the correct words.

Comment: [Can't reproduce with Chrome](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zKEf1.png). Please specify your browser and OS.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Updated the question with browser and OS.

Comment: @AmalMurali OK, Windows 7 here so it means something in Ubuntu cause this. Maybe your fonts are corrupted?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Nope, [this works fine on Firefox](http://i.imgur.com/23rqQ0c.png).

Comment: @AmalMurali weird. Try upgrading to Chrome 31.0.1650.48 hopefully it would solve this.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Updated, but the issue is still there.

Comment: That guy is a part of Pekka's name, not of the other guy

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8EYj.png) with the latest Chrome, Firefox or Safari on the latest OS X either.

Comment: @Arjan: Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: For the record, the culprit causing your latest issue is [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1458648/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still am not fully sure what caused this issue but I guess that was because Chrome couldn't find the requested glyph (`웃`) in the available font. Anyway, I was able to get it working. Here's what I  did:

1. Re-installed Google Chrome
2. Re-installed system fonts:

   ```
   sudo apt-get --reinstall install msttcorefonts
   ```
3. Regenerate the font cache (to avoid logout / login):

   ```
   sudo fc-cache -fv
   ```
4. Install some available font-packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ttf-indic-fonts-core ttf-kacst-one ttf-khmeros-core ttf-lao ttf-punjabi-fonts ttf-takao-pgothic ttf-thai-tlwg ttf-unfonts-core ttf-wqy-microhei
   ```
5. Tada!

I'm just posting this if in case someone encounters this issue in future. And thanks goes to @Arjan for all the [valuable advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214110/220538)).

Answer (score 3):

This is not related to some CSS or font size; it's an issue with a font on your Ubuntu.

I see all just fine:

[image]

Also, I [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYwpi.png) the additional whitespace where you typed `(웃  &nbsp;&nbsp;)` in your question, which on your computer apparently was needed to fix the erroneous font, even in a regular paragraph?

If you figure out which font is used for those characters, try to disable it and see if the browser then uses another font that does a better job.

To determine which font is used, see [How can I determine what font a browser is actually using to render some text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884177/how-can-i-determine-what-font-a-browser-is-actually-using-to-render-some-text/20830300#20830300) And beware that different browsers might use different fonts on the very same machine, like described there too.

(FileFormat.info [claims](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/c6c3) that *"U+C6C3 is not a valid unicode character"*. I don't know what that means.)

Comment: This works perfectly fine on Firefox. [Here's a screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xqhSH.png). Don't know why it isn't working on Chrome.

Comment: I copied the text into a Rich Text Editor as you suggested. For Chrome, it shows `Trebuchet MS`, and for Firefox, it shows `Arial`. That's probably the issue. Let me see if I can disable this font.

Comment: I'm afraid you didn't select the 웃 character then? I doubt your Trebuchet and Arial actually include that character, @Amal!

Comment: Also, @Amal, the copy-into-editor trick didn't work for me for Firefox. And your first screenshot already shows Firefox is using NanumGothicBold.

Comment: As an aside, @Amal, if you happen to use Hindi, and if the Hindi script also can combine letters into words like Arabic does, then you might want to look at the screenshots of the [problem with Arabic](http://superuser.com/questions/66295/arabic-in-powerpoint-on-mac/66305#66305) I once had. Just for future reference: if you ever see the combining of letters fail, you know it's related to font types that browsers prefer, and some bad font on your system. (To me, not paying attention at the time, both screenshots looked the same.)

Comment: I uninstalled all non-English fonts and that seems to have fixed the issue, but I can't still get it to work in Incognito. Not sure what's the issue, @Arjan.

Comment: On Windows I'd say: reboot, @Amal... (I don't know why incognito mode would use different fonts, unless a different CSS is loaded. Do you get the same font when copy/pasting in incognito mode?)

Comment: And did you get a different font than Trebuchet when truly only selecting that funny character after pasting, @Amal?

Comment: And, @Amal, see also http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/c6c3/fontsupport.htm and the [link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm?text=%EC%9B%83+-+U%2BC6C3) to "Local Font List tool" on that page.

Comment: Okay. Reeboted the machine 5 times, re-installed the default font package. This is the latest condition: http://i.imgur.com/KFHcHVD.png (btw: thanks for trying to help. I really appreciate it :), @Arjan

Comment: I'm afraid you're on your own there, @Amal. See also my comments about selecting *only* the funny character after pasting into a rich text editor. (I did not expect to see Trebuchet as a result.) And when all done, [here's some more screenshots to compare](http://superuser.com/questions/232636/displaying-unicode-on-chrome-vs-firefox)... Success!

Comment: Thanks for all the help, @Arjan. After browsing through *many* threads on Ask Ubuntu, Supe User (including the thread you just linked above :P), Google Groups etc. I was able to fix this. I re-installed Google Chrome from scratch, re-installed the system fonts and all available non-English font packages, with [this command](http://pastie.org/8585873). [SUCCESS!](http://i.imgur.com/PTn6X0W.png).

Comment: Yeah, I have posted an answer, @Arjan :)

Comment: What do you know, @Amal, while reposting the above to a better place, I found that [Chrome has a similar tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884177/how-can-i-determine-what-font-a-browser-is-actually-using-to-render-some-text/20830300#20830300).

Comment: Weird, @Amal, FileFormat.info [claims](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/c6c3) that "U+C6C3 is not a valid unicode character". I don't know what that means... And feel free to accept your own answer instead of mine.

Comment: Yeah, which was suggested in a [post](http://superuser.com/a/43492/224857) you linked before. And the `Computed` tab is showing differently for me: [see screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/x1KxHkQ.png).

Comment: Did you scroll down all the way, @Amal? (This is [a relatively new feature](https://twitter.com/chromiumdev/status/384098351353839616).)

Comment: Ah, how did I miss that. I see [this](http://i.imgur.com/pbzIwzM.png) now, @Arjan :)

Comment: So "UnDotum" it is, @Amal ;-) (Funny font names...)

Comment: Okay, now I'm confused. How did you determine UnDotum is the actual font used? Because it says `1 glyph`?

Comment: Indeed, @Amal, and the other 6 glyphs ("characters") are for "Pekka" and the space. (Also, Trebuchet is really a standard font, which on my Mac also did not include the funny guy.) Note that you could edit the page from within Chrome (just find the text in the lower left pane of your previous screenshot, double click that text, and remove the "Pekka" part) to see what the interesting character gives you.

Comment: I find it quite amusing that nobody here knows that the character `웃` (decomposed into ㅇ, ㅜ and ㅅ) is a Korean syllable character... :D

Comment: ..and btw the name of the font `UnDotum` (은돋움) is actually pronouced more like `eun-do-doom`.